# Query Multiple Ranges with Results in Row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I am trying to query five ranges with the results displayed across a single row.  To do this, I was using `{ }` with commas separating each range, but it's only giving me the first range in return.

Formula:

`=QUERY({A2:C2,D2:F2,G2:I2,J2:L2,M2:O2}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'")`

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ix4drHcmZiN3nRUEokgYv3Hinr0MXAG8BEUQH0dLpBo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

We need to use five QUERY functions, one for each set of columns, but then add something else to remove the blank columns. The following formula use JOIN and SPLIT:

`=SPLIT(JOIN(",",IFERROR({QUERY({A2:C2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'"),QUERY({D2:F2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'"),QUERY({G2:I2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'"),QUERY({J2:L2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'"),QUERY({M2:O2}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'")},"")),",")`

---

Original answer (keeped here because this answer got an upvote before the OP comment)

The comma separator (or slash if the spreadsheet use a comma as decimal separator) is used as column separators. Replace the comma by semicolon.

`=QUERY({A2:C2;D2:F2;G2:I2;J2:L2;M2:O2}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='USA'")`

Comment: I was hoping to keep the results in the same row, which is why I was thinking the commas would work.  How can I keep it in one row?

Comment: Now I understand. We need to use  five QUERY functions, one for each set of columns, but then add something else to remove the blank columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(
 {A2:C2;D2:F2;G2:I2;J2:L2;M2:O2}," ","♦"),"where Col3='USA'")),,50000)))," "),"♦"," "))
```

[image: 0]